# How do I calculate the sunrise and sunset in flutter?

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart

I would like to be able to change the text on a screen from day to night, depending on the the sun has set, or not. I found this api (https://sunrise-sunset.org/api) and more recently this package sunrise_sunset: "^1.0.3", but I am having difficulty.

This is part of a much bigger project that will be a map (google_maps) that will automatically change theme depending on the time of day(sunrise and sunset)

I know that whenever you use await, you have to make the class async, which I have done, but I am getting errors.

I have simply copied the code in the package example tab into my project

https://pub.dev/packages/sunrise_sunset#-example-tab-

I really am stuck with this, so any help would be very much appreciated.

thanks

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sunrise_sunset/sunrise_sunset.dart';

void main() => runApp(JsonApiDemo());

class JsonApiDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  JsonApiDemo({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _JsonApiDemoState createState() => _JsonApiDemoState();
}

class _JsonApiDemoState extends State<JsonApiDemo> async {

  var response = await SunriseSunset.getResults(latitude: 39.001735, longitude: -119.752744);

  if (response.success) {
    print('Sunrise: ${response.data.sunrise}');
    print('Sunset: ${response.data.sunset}');
  } else {
    print(response.error);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Hello World!',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Hello World!'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Missing concrete implementation of State.build.
Try implementing the missing method, or make the class abstract.

A class declaration must have a body, even if it is empty.
Try adding an empty body.

Functions must have an explicit list of parameters.
Try adding a parameter list.

The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'.

The declaration 'build' isn't referenced.
Try removing the declaration of 'build'.

Comment: You don't mark classes `async` - you mark methods (or top level functions). You also have some statements (the `if` etc) that aren't even in a method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - don't mark a class as `async` - only functions can be async.

2 - you should call the package from an async function. The simplest way to do that is from the `initState` method - note `initState` itself is not async - so you will need another method.

3 - in that async method, store the results and call `setState` so that the widget is rebuilt to show them

4 - in `build` you need to be able to cope with the gap while the results are being fetched - use a progress indicator, etc. (I've just replaced the result with the word *working*).

```
class _JsonApiDemoState extends State<JsonApiDemo> {
  DateTime sunrise;
  DateTime sunset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSunData();
  }

  void getSunData() async {
    var response = await SunriseSunset.getResults(
      latitude: 39.001735,
      longitude: -119.752744,
    );

    if (response.success) {
      var data = response.data;
      setState(() {
        sunrise = data.sunrise;
        sunset = data.sunset;
      });

      print('Sunrise: $sunrise');
      print('Sunset: $sunset');
    } else {
      print(response.error);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Hello World!',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Hello World!'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(sunrise == null ? 'Working...' : '$sunrise-$sunset'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Richard,

Thanks so much. I can't believe I put async on a class and not a method. One of those days yesterday and couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Appreciate your time and effort.